# Elastic Beanstalk environments blocked with following Error message about RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am unable to access either of my two environments within the same elastic beanstalk application, the error message for both is:

**A problem occurred while loading your page: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:rds:dbinstance', OptionName: 'HasCoupledDatabase'): Unknown configuration setting.**

I have no idea how to approach this problem (or even what it means to be honest). Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT :**

This message appears to have been caused by an AWS update. It seems the best place to report is to write on the AWS Dev Forums.

I had started a thread regarding this issue here, please add your voice: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=344213&tstart=0

Comment: How are you trying to connect to RDS from an app running in Elastic Beanstalk. Did you set the required Inbound Rules?

Comment: @smac2020 - I can't access the env to check config, if I remember correctly it was a standard RDS ebdb set up for php linux mysql. Is there anything I should be looking for in particular?

Comment: I would open up the RDS console in the AWS Management console and look at the settings - including the defined inbound rules that govern who can access the database.

Comment: @smac2020 each env's RDS has the same inboundRules set up [within ec2], 1 rule,simply: Type: All TCP, // source Custom, (value: unique EC2 Sec Grp string)//

Comment: Are you using CodePipeline/CodeDeploy? Seeing the same issue out of nowhere this AM but only for our envs that get deployed by pipeline.

Comment: @david no, i upload (zip file) and deploy through the EBS interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Setup AWS CLI
2. Create a .json file with the following content:

```
[
  {
    "Namespace": "aws:rds:dbinstance",
    "OptionName": "HasCoupledDatabase"
  }
]
```

3. Run the following command, changing YOUR_* to your values:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name "YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME" --version-label "YOUR_VERSION_LABEL" --region="YOUR_REGION" --options-to-remove file://PATH_TO_JSON
```

4. Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks - but a question, doesn't the error say that the JSON settings are actually exactly as you want us to input - and THAT is the problem, what is the rationale here to fix it like this if is an internal error, in short; What is happening?

Comment: This worked for me, notice the option passed was --options-to-remove. I also was able to do it without the version label option.

Comment: This does resolve 'the problem' - If you get a message in the CMD saying "An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the UpdateEnvironment operation: Environment named XXXX is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready." Then simply in the Application page, choose Environment, Actions "Restart Server"

Comment: I believe that AWS changed the name of that option, or something like that, but some applications weren't updated with it, therefore leading to this problem.
I thought that just removing this setting was going to create another issue with the RDS Instance of the application, but it does not seems to be the case, everything is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Download and setup Aws CLI if not already done
 2. To download aws cli visit  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html#cliv2-windows-install)
 3. To set up aws cli follow :
 4. Go to location where aws cli installed i.e. C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>
 5. To confirm whether installed or not -> open cmd-> type aws --version
 6. if response is like (aws-cli/1.7.24 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8) then OK.
 7. In CMd itself to configure aws type -> aws configure 
 8. Enter following data as asked in steps by aws cli :

AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json

Note : here region and default output can be skipped by pressing enter and Access Key and secret key can be generated by following these steps in your aws account 

click bell icon in left side of region on top right corner -> My Security Credentials -> Access keys (access key ID and secret access key) -> create new or use existing.

 

 9. type aws s3 ls , on cmd and if it shows your s3 bucket then connection has been made succesfully.
10. Create a json file named aws_issue.json on desktop
11. paste below content in aws_issue.json and save
[
  {
    "Namespace": "aws:rds:dbinstance",
    "OptionName": "HasCoupledDatabase"
  }
]

12. type the following command in single line on cmd with your environment , its version , region , path to aws_issue.json


   aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name 
   "**YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME**" --version-label "**YOUR_VERSION_LABEL**" -- 
   region="**YOUR_REGION**" --options-to-remove 
   file://C:\Users\**pathAsPerYourMachine**\aws_issue.json
```

Comment: Thanks - but a question, doesn't the error say that the JSON settings are actually exactly as you want us to input - and THAT is the problem, what is the rationale here to fix it like this if is an internal error, in short; What is happening?

Comment: Don't add a code quote for your full answer. Add code quote only for the code in your answer.